# R: Subset between group values and several columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a df like that:

```
> head(dt)

     Ref.     Date1               Date2     Value
 1: 2018146   2018-01-25      2018-02-25    9281.85
 2: 2018146   2018-01-25      2018-04-25    9281.85
 3: 2018150   2018-01-25      2018-02-25    5865.48
 4: 2018150   2018-01-25      2018-04-25    5865.48
 5: 2018306   2018-01-31      2018-03-25    9596.81
 6: 2010306   2018-01-31      2018-05-01    9596.81
```

I have Ref. duplicates because in the value Date, Date2 and Value there are some differences.

I want to keep only the Ref. that have differences between all the other columns:

for example:

I want to keep that rows:

```
Ref.     Date1               Date2     Value
2016487   2017-05-01      2017-06-30   -5343.68
2016487   2016-04-29      2016-05-31   -7451.18
```

I want to skip that rows (just differing in one column not in all 3):

```
  Ref.     Date1       Date2     Value
 2015778 2016-10-27 2016-12-26 -108.01
 2015778 2016-10-27 2016-12-26 -108.00
```

I have tried to do that:

```
x %>% group_by(Invoice) %>% 
filter(!duplicated(x$Date1)&!duplicated(x$Date2)&!duplicated(x$Value))
```

But not working.

Comment: In the example you posted, would there be any rows matching the criteria?  What if there is only one row per group?

Comment: Yes, there are rows matching the criteria, all Ref. are duplicated at least twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a data.table.  After grouping by 'Ref.', `unlist` the Subset of data.table (`.SD`), `if` the `length` of unlisted elements are equal to the `length` of `unique` elements (`uniqueN`), then get the Subset of Data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt[, {
        un <- unlist(.SD)
        if(length(un) == uniqueN(un)) .SD
      }, Ref.]
```

NOTE: Here we assume that all the values are distinct for each 'Ref.' i.e. even 'Date1' and 'Date2' values are not the same.

If the condition is to only check the unique values in each column and not across all the columns

```
dt[dt[, .I[Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) == 1))], Ref.]$V1]
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
   group_by(Ref.) %>%
   filter_all(all_vars(n_distinct(.) == n()))
```

Comment: It works, May I ask you the logic of the solution?  Thank you so much.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguez  I just updated with some description